# vetor de Matriz de registros

Tags: c, struct

Foi pedido em sala de aula que os alunos replicassem um esquema desenhado pelo professor. Nesse esquema ele fez um vetor, dentro de cada posição ele fez uma matriz e dentro de cada posição da matriz ele desenhou uma estrutura contendo nome, endereço e idade. Que fique claro que não estou pedindo que resolvam pra mim, quero apenas que me expliquem a lógica desse exercício.

Segue o que fiz de código até o momento:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <windows.h>

struct Pessoa{
    char nome[40];
    char endereco[100];
    int idade;
};

void mostrar(Pessoa vetor[][2]){
    for(int i=0; i<2; i++){
        for(int j=0; j<2; j++){
            printf("\nCOD-%d\n", i);
            printf("\tNome: %s", vetor[i][j].nome);
            printf("\n\tEndereco: %s", vetor[i][j].endereco);
            printf("\n\tIdade: %d", vetor[i][j].idade); 
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

int main(void){
    Pessoa clientes[2][2];

    for(int i=0; i<2; i++)
        for(int j=0; j<2; j++){
            fflush(stdin);
            printf("\nCOD-%d%d\n", i,j);
            printf("\tNome: ");
            gets(clientes[i][j].nome);
            printf("\tEndereco: ");
            gets(clientes[i][j].endereco);
            printf("\tIdade: ");
            scanf("%d", &clientes[i][j].idade); 
        }

    system("cls");
    mostrar(clientes);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Era bem simples:
Só montar essa estrutura.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct dados{
    char *nome;
    char *endereco;
    int idade;
};

struct matriz{
    struct dados mat[3][3];
};

main(){
    struct matriz vet[3];
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simples, vamos la na função main você irá preencher o vetor da struct pessoa, você irá pegar na posição 0, 1 ou seja 2 linhas e 2 colunas, nessa linha você está criando uma matriz de 3 linhas e 3 colunas da struct pessoa

```
Pessoa clientes[2][2];

Aqui na main você irá percorrer as linhas da matriz e as colunas passando os dados para a clientes que referencia a struct criada, basicamente oque faz é em na linha 0 e coluna 0 passa um nome idade e endereço, linha 0 e coluna 1 passa um nome idade e endereço, e assim por diante, e na mostrar ao invés de receber ele mostra os dados passados

int main(void){
    Pessoa clientes[2][2];

    for(int i=0; i<2; i++)
        for(int j=0; j<2; j++){
            fflush(stdin);
            printf("\nCOD-%d%d\n", i,j);
            printf("\tNome: ");
            //Aqui você pegará o nome
            gets(clientes[i][j].nome);
            printf("\tEndereco: ");
            //Aqui você pegará o endereço
            gets(clientes[i][j].endereco);
            printf("\tIdade: ");
             //Aqui você pegará a idade
            scanf("%d", &clientes[i][j].idade); 
        }

    system("cls");
    //Aqui chama a função mostrar
    mostrar(clientes);
    return 0;
}
```

Na função mostrar você recebe a matriz e percorre ela, linha 0 e linha 1, coluna 0 e 1 e mostra os dados cadastrados nela

```
void mostrar(Pessoa vetor[][2]){
    for(int i=0; i<2; i++){
        for(int j=0; j<2; j++){
            printf("\nCOD-%d\n", i);
            //Mostra o nome
            printf("\tNome: %s", vetor[i][j].nome);
             //Mostra o endereço
            printf("\n\tEndereco: %s", vetor[i][j].endereco);
             //Mostra a idade
            printf("\n\tIdade: %d", vetor[i][j].idade); 
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Assim que você fala?

Dentro da função main mesmo você irá criar um vetor do tipo Pessoa, e armazenar as matrizes da struct Pessoa dentro do vetor e mostrar

```
int main(void){
    Pessoa clientes[2][2];
    Pessoa clienteGuarda[5];
    //variavel auxiliar
    int aux = 0;
    for(int i=0; i<2; i++){
        for(int j=0; j<2; j++){
            fflush(stdin);
            printf("\nCOD-%d%d\n", i,j);
            printf("\tNome: ");
            gets(clientes[i][j].nome);
            printf("\tEndereco: ");
            gets(clientes[i][j].endereco);
            printf("\tIdade: ");
            scanf("%d", &clientes[i][j].idade); 
        }
    }


    system("cls");
    mostrar(clientes);
    //for para percorrer o vetor e adicionar matrizes a ele
     for(int i=0; i<2; i++){
        for(int j=0; j<2; j++){
            //adiciona o struct armazenado em cada posição da matriz
            clienteGuarda[aux] = clientes[i][j];
            //Printa os dados do vetor 
            printf("%s",clienteGuarda[aux].nome);
            printf("%s",clienteGuarda[aux].endereco);
            printf("%d",clienteGuarda[aux].idade);
            aux++;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Esse foi o código que fiz, mas ainda preciso que a matriz clientes fique dentro de um vetor[3].

Comment: Como assim não entendi sua dúvida então... você quer que tenha mais uma linha e mais uma coluna?

Comment: No momento consegui fazer uma matriz de struct, para chegar ao que o professor pediu, falta colocar essa matriz dentro de um vetor (cada posição do vetor terá uma matriz de struct)

Comment: Irei editar a publicação